# PageSpeed Insights: API vs node_module

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I have noticed that the execution via the PSI API is done automatically via a location in (i would gess) the USA (and i dont think i can set a location by myself for the api?).

Would the tests use the location of my server if i implement the tests via the node_module, or would this make no difference?

Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: What node module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/pagespeed-insights? I am asking as you can run the whole of "lighthouse" on your own server https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse, which is the engine that powers Page Speed Insights (PSI) and this is written in NodeJS. As far as I am aware Google does not indicate where their servers are for PSI and as the PSI website consumes its own API I don't think it would make a difference.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie ok and when i´m running lighthouse on my server, it would run the tests from my serverlocation? So i could run the tests for example from a german location, if my servers are located in germany?

Sry i´m kinda new in this field

Comment: Wherever your server is located it will run from there. It runs on your server using chromium and calculates the score directly on your server. No outside information (other than your server requesting the website itself) goes anywhere else. However be warned, it is not that easy to get lighthouse working on your own server (not very difficult either but just a heads up it may take you a while).

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Would you mind telling me briefly about the problems with the implementation of Google Lighthouse or giving me a few suitable keywords for my research?